# SMTP outbound : spoof ipv4 Receiver from

Tags: python, email, smtp, ipv6, outbound

SMTP outbound traffic, how is it possible to hide the ipv4 in the email sent ?

I'm sending emails using ipv6 :

```
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, source_address=("2a00:b700:5::1:1fe",0, 0, 0))
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.login('mygmail@gmail.com', 'mypwd')
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Good Morning"
    msg['From'] = 'mygmail@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = "receipient@gmail.com"
    MIMEText("Hello", 'html')
    msg.attach(part2)
    smtpserver.sendmail(msg['From'], "receipient@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
```

The receiver got the email source like that :

[image]

from : [IPv4] ([ipv6])

How can i hide [IPv4] using domain for example ? i've seen on a php application that they hide IPv4 using a domain for example : abc.xyz (even without owning this domain)

So their message source is like : from : [Domain] ([ipv6])

Comment: You can specify the name to use there with either the `local_hostname` argument to `smtplib.SMTP()` or the `name` argument to `ehlo()`

Comment: @Barmar i tried this smtpserver.login('test@gmail.com', 'test',local_hostname="test.xyz")
i got error : login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'local_hostname' , and tried this :         smtpserver.ehlo(name="test.com")  i received my email but with ipv4 showing not the test.com

Comment: I don't think you can hide this, the `Received:` headers are inserted by the receiving email server, and unless you can change its configuration, you'll have to live with your email address in the email's headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `local_hostname` argument to `smtplib.SMTP()` to override the default hostname.

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, local_hostname = 'spoofed.exxample.com', source_address=("2a00:b700:5::1:1fe",0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: i tried :         smtpserver.login('test@gmail.com', 'test', local_hostname = 'spoofed.exxample.com')
  and got this error : TypeError: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'local_hostname'

Comment: I don't know why, it's documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP

Comment: It worked, i shouldn't make both local_hostname and name on ehlo too, only one of them

Comment: Please, do you have any idea how to spoof the from ? for example instead of mygmail@gmail.com -> Juan Carlos

Comment: Just put the desired address in `$msg['From']`. You may need to configure your gmail account settings to allow sending from that address.

Comment: Go to your Gmail settings, go to the **Accounts and Import** tab, and add all the sender addresses you want to use to **Send mail as**